# What does `options` in puppet providers do? Fx in useradd.rb

Tags: ruby, puppet

Can someone explain how the `options` work in puppet provider or provide a link that explains it. Fx this line

```
options :password_min_age, :flag => "-m", :method => :sp_min
```

found in [useradd.rb](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/master/lib/puppet/provider/user/useradd.rb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are options to command line programs used by puppet, to provide a desired functionality.

In your example, the option is further use when puppet modifies user password expiry information. To do that puppet make use of cli command `chage`.

First puppet defines commands (line 12):

```
commands :add => "useradd", :delete => "userdel", :modify => "usermod", :password => "chage"
```

Next after defining commands options it makes use of them (line 199):

```
[command(:password),age_limits.collect { |property| [flag(property), @resource.should(property)]}, @resource[:name]].flatten
```

In result puppet calls something like:

```
chage -m MIN_DAYS -M MAX_DAYS
```

More about chage [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chage).